# how to start zoneminder server

Tags: php, ubuntu, zoneminder

i  install the zoneminder as per their instruction give by zone minder.After installation they gave a command to start zomeminder server

"zmpkg.pl start" but when i use this i got this error .

```
Warning, overriding installed ./zm.conf file with local copy
Bareword "ZM_PATH_LOGS" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/share/perl5/ZoneMinder/Debug.pm line 265.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/ZoneMinder.pm line 34.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/ZoneMinder.pm line 34.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/zmpkg.pl line 45.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/zmpkg.pl line 45.
```

Comment: check http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Server_12.04_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.25.0_the_easy_way

Answer (score 0):

Zoneminder requires a web server and a background task:

```
 service httpd start
 service zoneminder start
```

From [Start ZoneMinder](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Documentation#Start_ZoneMinder)

Comment: service zoneminder start
Starting ZoneMinder: Bareword "ZM_PATH_LOGS" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/share/perl5/ZoneMinder/Debug.pm line 265.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/ZoneMinder.pm line 34.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/ZoneMinder.pm line 34.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/zmpkg.pl line 45.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/zmpkg.pl line 45.
failure

Answer (score 0):

Look if there is something wrong with SQL dump import

In my case, in installation manual for Ubuntu 14.04 it is asked to import database dump with

```
MySQL -uroot -p < /usr/share/zoneminder/db/zm_create.sql
```

this failed and halted due to error with creation of 'Logs' table. I then edited the SQL file to add

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Logs`;
```

before

```
CREATE TABLE `Logs` (
```

and then imported the dump successfully.  The `zm` service then started correctly without errors